# How to fix ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero when calculating Gaussian probability

Tags: python, probability, gaussian, normal-distribution

I'm trying to calculate Gaussian probability, but when I run it through my data I get `ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero`

here's the code:

```
def GaussianProbability(x, mean, std):
    exponent = math.exp(-(math.pow(x-mean,2)/(2*math.pow(std,2))))
    return (1 / (math.sqrt(2*math.pi) * std)) * exponent
```

and the complete error log:

```
ZeroDivisionError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-b3fd5204c6fa> in <module>
----> 1 precisions_PDZ1,MAP,recalls_PDZ1,fp_rates_PDZ1 = CV_results(PDZ1_graphs,PDZ1_targets,'undirected')

<ipython-input-14-044940745269> in CV_results(list_graphs, list_targets, network_type, multi)
      7     for part in tqdm(range(5)):
      8 
----> 9         probabilities_0,predictions = prediction(list_graphs[part], list_targets[part], network_type, multi)
     10 
     11         if recalls == [] and fp_rates == []:

<ipython-input-12-beeed13223ea> in prediction(graph, actual_edges, network_type, multi)
     11 
     12     for i in tqdm(range(len(X_test))):
---> 13         prob = ClassProbabilities(summaries, prob_class, X_test[i])
     14         if (prob[0]+prob[1])==0:
     15             # both probabilities are too low

<ipython-input-11-286b09a753e9> in ClassProbabilities(summaries, prob_class, x)
      8         for i in range(len(classSummaries)):  # for every attribute
      9             mean, std = classSummaries[i]
---> 10             probabilities[classValue] *= GaussianProbability(x[i], mean, std)
     11 
     12     return probabilities

<ipython-input-10-4a13cc5a69b2> in GaussianProbability(x, mean, std)
      1 def GaussianProbability(x, mean, std):
----> 2     exponent = math.exp(-(math.pow(x-mean,2)/(2*math.pow(std,2))))
      3     return (1 / (math.sqrt(2*math.pi) * std)) * exponent

ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```

Comment: What should your function returns when `std=0`. That is when all of your numbers are equal?

Comment: is `std=0`? that would result in such an error. also it would not make much sense mathematically... (unless you consider [distributions/deneralized functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics))). maybe also consider using [`NormalDist`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.NormalDist).

Comment: based on this https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/233834/what-is-the-normal-distribution-when-standard-deviation-is-zero
I've done this, it worked, but how small should be my std2? is this approach correct?
`
def GaussianProbability(x, mean, std):
    if (std == 0.0):
        std2 = 0.01
        exponent = math.exp(-(math.pow(x-mean,2)/(2*math.pow(std2,2))))
        return (1 / (math.sqrt(2*math.pi) * std2)) * exponent
    else:
        exponent = math.exp(-(math.pow(x-mean,2)/(2*math.pow(std,2))))
        return (1 / (math.sqrt(2*math.pi) * std)) * exponent
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your function needs to have an `else` statement when you standerdv is equal to Zero

you can see this reference it might help [What is the normal distribution when standard deviation is zero?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/233834/what-is-the-normal-distribution-when-standard-deviation-is-zero)

Answer (score 1):

The only place where such error might occur is when `(2*math.pow(std,2)) == 0`.
Which means that for some data your `std == 0` this happens when all samples have the exact same value.

You would need to handle such case!

Unless you wish to implement it yourself (not recommended) you can use `scipy` package:

```
import scipy
scipy.stats.norm(0, 1).pdf(0)
```

Visit [scipy docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html)

You can also use the builtin statistics package python offers (better idea for simple and faster calculations). Check it out [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.NormalDist.pdf)